# After Trigger effect in SQL Server 2005 transactional publication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers, database-replication

On publisher table P1 we have after trigger on `last_update_time` column which is fired when any data is updated. On subscriber table S1 we have an insert trigger to audit all the data changes into audit table SA1.

When any data is changed on P1 2 records are inserted into SA1.

1. The data changes
2. update last_date_time data which is the result of after trigger on P1.

How can I manage to audit only one record on SA1 for any change on P1  including `last_update_time column`?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I am not able to upload screen shots of tables as uploading images needs at least 10 reputation. Any alternate to better explain my question?

Comment: I am guessing you didn't read that article very thoroughly. Screen shots don't help, what helps is ddl to create tables and insert statement to generate some sample data. You can do this directly in your question or you can http://sqlfiddle.com